# Facebook Like button moves and becomes 1000px high after going back to a page

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

We're seeing a weird behavior with the facebook like button. Use case is as follows:

1. Load a page, facebook like button is in the header.
2. Click a link, go to a new page, facebook like button is on that page too.
3. Click back button.
4. Like button on the previous page has now moved ~100px to the right, taken on `position: absolute` and is now 1000px high, with a transparent element that covers all elements lower than the FB like button on the page.
5. Click forward. Second page has the same bug.

Here's some of the other weird behaviors we're seeing with it:

- There's a span inside the FB div that just has a height and width added to the element style. It starts out as 200px x 1000px. Occasionally it will suddenly jump to 0px x 0px -- so far I see no rhyme or reason as to why.
- Some of our pages have a lot of FB like buttons. They all exhibit the same behavior.
- On iPad, the FB button takes on `display: block` after coming back to a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/663421210369743/

We've fixed this using the following:

```
.fb-like {
  display: inline-block !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 81px !important;
  height: 22px !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1002;
}
.fb-like > span {
  vertical-align: top !important;
  min-width: 81px !important;
  min-height: 22px !important;
}
.fb-like > span > iframe {
  min-width: 81px !important;
  min-height: 22px !important;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I changed all `min-width` and `min-height` properties to `max-width` and `max-height` though :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped us a lot ! 
But seeing as we had to have a like button with various languages ('Like' becomes 'Synes godt om' in danish !), we deleted the widths in your code and set up a little resize function : 
        `var fbResize = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('.fb_iframe_widget').first().width() != ('.fb_iframe_widget > span').first().width()) {
                $('.fb-like').width($('.fb_iframe_widget > span').first().width());
                clearInterval(fbResize);
            }
        }, 100);`